# Alignment in Table form

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm having some trouble with TableForm in a plot inset (see image).

[image]

1) The point markers are under/above the line markers (but I noticed that always the case also in the plots themselves, which is a bit annoying).

2) Is there a way of having "Head1" aligned with the text of the first column instead of with the markers? (in the code I added blank spaces for "manually aligning" them)

3) The most annoying bit: why the first column is not aligned with the second column? "test1" and "test3" are below the lines of "test2" and "test4"

See below the example the code I used for generating the plot:

```
a = Exp[-#^2] & /@ Range[-5, 5, 0.1];
b = Exp[-(# + 2)^2] & /@ Range[-5, 5, 0.1];

plot = Show[
  ListPlot[
   {a, b},
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[0.003]], 
     Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.003], Dashed]}
   , PlotMarkers -> {{\[FilledCircle], 14}, {\[FilledSquare], 16}}]

  ,
  ListPlot[
   {a, b},
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[0.003]], 
     Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.003], Dashed]}
   , Joined -> True,
   InterpolationOrder -> 2],

  Epilog -> {Inset[TableForm[
      {
       {LineLegend[{Red}, {"test1"}, LabelStyle -> {Black, 16}, 
         LegendMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 15}, 
         LegendMarkerSize -> 30], Style[Text["test2"], Black, 16]},
       {LineLegend[{Directive[Blue, Dashed]}, {"test3"}, 
         LabelStyle -> {Black, 16}, 
         LegendMarkers -> {\[FilledSquare], 18}, 
         LegendMarkerSize -> 30], Style[Text["test4"], Black, 16]}
       }, 
      TableHeadings -> {None, {Style[Text["         Head1"], Black, 
          16], Style[Text["Head2"], Bold, Black, 16]}}
      , TableSpacing -> {0, 2}
      ],
     Scaled[{0.8, 0.6}]
     ]},

  Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 20},
  ImageSize -> Large
  ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `LineLegend` with a custom layout

```
ClearAll[ gridLegend]
gridLegend[headers_List, labels_List, o1 : OptionsPattern[]][colors_, 
    o2 : OptionsPattern[]] :=  Module[{grid}, 
  grid[pairs_] := Grid[{Prepend[headers, ""], ## & @@ 
      Transpose[Prepend[labels, pairs[[All, 1]]]]}, o1, 
    Alignment -> Center, Dividers -> {False, {False, True}}];
  LineLegend[colors, ConstantArray["", Length @ colors], 
   LegendLayout -> grid, o2, LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, 18}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 20}]]
```

**Examples:**

```
headers = Style[#, 16] & /@ {"Head1", "Head2"};
colors = {Red, Directive[Blue, Dashed]};
labels = "test" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[Length[colors] Length[headers]];
labelmatrix = Transpose @ ArrayReshape[Style[#, 16] & /@ labels, 
   {Length @ colors, Length @ headers}];
gridLegend[headers, labelmatrix][colors]
```

[image]

Change `colors2 = {Red, Directive[Blue, Dashed], Green};` in place of `colors` above to get

[image]

Use`headers2 = Style[#, 16] & /@ {"Head1", "Head2", "Head3"};` in place of `header` above to get

[image]

Use a 3X3 label list with `colors2` and `headers2`:

[image]

Use as `PlotLegends`:

```
ListPlot[{a, b}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle->{Directive[Red, Thickness[0.003]], Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.003], Dashed]},
 PlotMarkers -> {{\[FilledCircle], 14}, {\[FilledSquare], 16}}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[gridLegend[headers, labelmatrix][Automatic], Scaled[{0.8, 0.6}]]]
```

[image]

Use with `Legended` and `Show`:

```
show = Show[ListPlot[{a, b}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle->{Directive[Red, Thickness[.003]], Directive[Blue, Thickness[.003], Dashed]},
  PlotMarkers -> {{\[FilledCircle], 14}, {\[FilledSquare], 16}}], 
 ListPlot[{a, b}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle->{Directive[Red, Thickness[.003]], Directive[Blue, Thickness[.003], Dashed]},
  Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 2], Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 20}, ImageSize -> Large]; 
Legended[show, Placed[gridLegend[headers, labelmatrix][{Red, 
    Directive[Dashed, Blue]}, LegendMarkerSize -> {70, 30}], Scaled[{0.8, 0.6}]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, define a custom layout function using `TableForm` to be used as `LegendLayout` option setting:

```
ClearAll[tableLayout]
tableLayout[headers_List, labels_List][pairs_] := 
 TableForm[Transpose[Prepend[labels, pairs[[All, 1]]]], 
  TableHeadings -> {None, Prepend[headers, ""]}, TableAlignments -> Center]
```

**Example:**

```
LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"", ""}, LegendLayout -> tableLayout[headers, labelmatrix], 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, 16}, LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, 18}, LegendMarkerSize -> 30]
```

[image]

Comment: what to say.. thanks, that's very very useful :)

Comment: @Fraccalo, thank you for the accept.

Comment: I modded a tiny bit the first function you proposed, so that it's more suitable to my purposes: I added some space between lines and columns, and there is the option for manually give the markers (see comment below)

Comment: ClearAll[gridLegend]
gridLegend[headers_List, labels_List, markers_: {Automatic, 18}, 
   o1 : OptionsPattern[]][colors_, o2 : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{grid}, 
  grid[pairs_] := 
   Grid[{Prepend[headers, ""], ## & @@ 
      Transpose[Prepend[labels, pairs[[All, 1]]]]}, o1, 
    Alignment -> Center, Dividers -> {False, {False, True}}, 
    Spacings -> {2, 1.2}];
  LineLegend[colors, ConstantArray["", Length@colors], 
   LegendLayout -> grid, o2, LegendMarkers -> markers, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 20}]]